# Adding timeDilation in one screen slows down the loading of other pages in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator, flutter-animation

I had followed the hero animation tutorial in flutter. When i tried to add one more sceen i just noticed that the timedilation property is affecting the loading time of other screens also. And I had tried resetting the variable to zero but it didn't work as expected.

```
class PhotoHero extends StatelessWidget {
 const PhotoHero({Key key, this.photo, this.onTap, this.width})
  : super(key: key);

 final String photo;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final double width;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SizedBox(
  width: width,
  child: Hero(
    tag: photo,
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Image.asset(
          photo,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);  }}

class HeroAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
timeDilation = 10.0; // 1.0 means normal animation speed.

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Basic Hero Animation'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: PhotoHero(
      photo: 'images/flippers-alpha.png',
      width: 300.0,
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
      },
    ),
  ),
); }}

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
routes: {
  '/': (context) => HeroAnimation(),
  '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  '/third': (context) => ThirdScreen(),
},  ));}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Title(color: Colors.red, child: Text('Dummy Title')),
  ),
); }}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Flippers Page'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    // Set background to blue to emphasize that it's a new route.
    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: PhotoHero(
      photo: 'images/flippers-alpha.png',
      width: 100.0,
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/third');
      },
    ),
  ),
);  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `timeDilation` it will affect the other screens animation time. Because it's a global property. In order to go back to the normal animation speed you have to change that variable value to `1.0` which is the normal animation speed.

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 timeDilation = 8.0; // Since we need the animation to slow down.
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 timeDilation = 1.0; // Changing the value to normal animation speed.
}
```

> As a note, if you are coming back using back button the build method won't get called so the timeDilation value won't change to the value of the screen which you're in. In this case you've to make your screen as StatefulWidget then you can set the value on the life cycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as timeDilation is global property sort of , so you need to set it every time you need to change the speed of your animation `onTap` will be perfect place to do so,

check the modified code below

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class PhotoHero extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoHero({Key key, this.photo, this.onTap, this.width})
      : super(key: key);

  final String photo;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final double width;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      child: Hero(
        tag: photo,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Image.asset(
              photo,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );  }}

class HeroAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //timeDilation = 10.0; // 1.0 means normal animation speed.

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic Hero Animation'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PhotoHero(
          photo: '/images/flippers-alpha.png',
          width: 300.0,
          onTap: () {
            timeDilation = 10.0;

            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ); }}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => HeroAnimation(),
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      '/third': (context) => ThirdScreen(),
    },  ));}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeDilation = 1.0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Title(color: Colors.red, child: Text('Dummy Title')),
      ),
    ); }}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //timeDilation = 1.0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flippers Page'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // Set background to blue to emphasize that it's a new route.
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: PhotoHero(
          photo: '/images/flippers-alpha.png',
          width: 100.0,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/third');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );  }}
```